# unable to create android release: java.io.FileNotFoundException (../node_modules/react-native/undefined)

Tags: react-native

When executing ./assembleRelease from my react-native project's android folder project, I get the following error:

```
12:47:38.876 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' during up-to-date check.
12:47:38.876 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/michiel/Sites/Erbij/erbij/node_modules/react-native/undefined (Operation not supported on socket)
```

iOS releases are fine and local development werkt for both Android and iOS. Does anybody have an idea where to start search? Tried running with `--verbose`, `--info` and `--debug`, no luck.

I've also tried stripping my entire javascript code, and have App.js be a simple component that renders and empty view.

Answer (score 5):

I solve this error by deleting a file "node_modules/react-native/undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I ran react-native-git-upgrade which must've removed some cache files, because there are no changes showing up in git